# java: is using a final static int = 1 better than just a normal 1?

Tags: java

I just saw a class (an big API module), where there is alot of stuff like

```
readParamString(Object params, int index)
```

and they have in that class 10 fields

```
final static int PARAM1 = 1
...
final static int PARAM10 = 10
```

which are being used with readParam functions

but you can also use a normal int like `readParamString(o, 1);`

is final static int somehow better than using a normal int ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring with the keywords `final static int`,
you will have a single instance of a variable that has the integer value of 1.
An important point is that this value cannot change
once declared with the keyword `final`.
Otherwise,
you can change the value of variable.
You use the keywords `final static` if you don't want to change the variable value anywhere your code.

Comment: None of these things are appropriate to int literals in Java, except if the constant value means something (which would be indicated by a name like `NUMBER_OF_WOGGLES_IN_A_BOGGLE` as opposed to `PARAM1`)

Answer (score 15):

One advantage of declaring a static final constant is to prevent multiple references to the same literal value througout the code, which could potentially lead to unwanted variation; e.g. if a programmer inadvertently changes one literal without changing the others.

In your example, I'd question the value of declaring a constant PARAM1 with the value 1, especially if this is private to the containing class and only referenced once.  If however, there was some semantic meaning to the literal value then it might be more useful; e.g.

```
public static final int LOAD_ACTION = 1;
public static final int SAVE_ACTION = 2;
public static final int DELETE_ACTION = 4;
public static final int MOVE_ACTION = 8;
```

However, typically an enum would be used instead of this approach.

Comment: But what if the value of 1 changes?!

Comment: @John: My point is that if PARAM1 is only being used in one place in code private to the class then there's little value in defining it.  Overuse of static final constants can make code unreadable IMHO.

Comment: +1, magic numbers in code should always be defined with a meaningful semantic name to make them readable.

Comment: they are actually PARAM1, PARAM2 ... that's the real names, they are used as indexes for reading params

Answer (score 9):

That's silly.

The reason for extracting numeric constants is to give them a telling name.  PARAM1..PARAM10 are not very telling.

Comment: +1. Another reason could be to track references, and be able to maintain them in one place. But a meaningful name would have been better there as well.

Comment: Note that the silly names may have a single purpose, namely to be able to document their usage with JavaDoc.

Answer (score 4):

In the example you give, I'd say that having the named values is not better than just using the int directly.  The parameter is a count, so the int representation of the parameter is just as descriptive as the named version.

This seems to be kind of like when I occasionally come across C code that has things like

```
#define ZERO 0
#define ONE 1
```

There's really not much point. In fact, when I see those names used (instead of when I'm looking at the definitions), I get tempted to jump to the defines to make sure the names aren't lying (It's been a long, long time, but, I've actually come across code that had FALSE defined to 1, -1 or something non-zero, for example, which is really, really bad).

---

Edit: on second look, it appears that the names might indicate which field in the first parameter that are of interest, in which case the names  might make more sense - as long as the names have some meaningful tie to the field rather than just the numeric offset.  It's hard to say whether or not that's the case, since you might be paraphrasing the code you're really working with.

Answer (score 1):

yes somehow better than using a normal int

But If you are using Java 5 or later `enum` is better than `final static` variables.

Comment: The "static final int" approach is still useful if you wish to encode multiple values in a single integer using one-hot encoding (whereby you bitwise-OR the different values together).

Comment: In this specific case, the final statics are completely useless.

Comment: @Adamski: for a real OO approach I'd recommend an `EnumSet` instead of the old-school bitwise-OR approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not done for the final static variable but to have telling names. And therefor even `PARAMETER1` is more telling than just `1`. Therefor may improve understanding while reading the code.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's because the variable is inlined by the compiler.