# What does "static final int" mean?

Tags: java, final

I'm new to java and the book surprisingly started using this without explaining it even once.
Why does stack overflow want me to write even more than I actually need?

Comment: I guess you need to get another book.

Comment: To encourage good questions. Sadly, the number of characters isn't always the best indicator of this. Have you considered going over some *other* Java tutorials and/or documentation? Or just wait to learn every detail, and get larger pictures first? There are a lot of other things it probably hasn't explained yet too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070669/java-is-using-a-final-static-int-1-better-than-just-a-normal-1

Comment: Don't try to find out what `static final int` means, try to find out what `static`, `final` and `int` mean seperately

Comment: If there's one stack overflow solution to a single question, then it will be better indexed by search engines.  Also, the people who originally asked it and answered it will continue to get views and points for it which is how the site works.  If you had a great solution, you wouldn't want 10 people giving the exact same one and getting your points :).

Comment: To the people saying 'try google' -- I just landed here from google. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`static` means that instead of each instance of the class having that variable, the variable belongs to the class as a whole.

`final` means that the values are constant and cannot be changed.

Basically what this means is that it's an integer that is constant for all instances of a certain class at all times.

Answer (score 6):

static --> the field is at class level, not at instance level. i.e, you can access the field using MyClass.myField.

final --> 
for primitives --> value can't change

for non-primitives --> you can't change the reference and point it to another object. Note : It is different from *immutability*.

Answer (score 2):

static - denotes class level member and memory is allocated only once, all objects will have access to the same memory reference

final - denotes a constant variable, value cannot be changed at anytime.

you can declare

```
class Login 
{
    public static final int USER = 1;   
    // We are not able to change the value during execution 
    public static final int ADMIN = 2;
}
```